# loop in php else part is not showing

Tags: php, loops

`else` part is not showing if `fromdate` & `todate` is not set in datepicker

```
if(isset($_GET['fromdate']) && (isset($_GET['todate'])))
{
    $from = $_GET['fromdate'];
    $to = $_GET['todate']; 
    $war = "and date between '$from' and '$to'";
}
else
{ 
    $war = "";
}
```

Comment: check for blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is sent, both fields exist. Maybe empty, but they are set (and `isset` condition is valid).

Use `!empty` instead.

```
if (!empty($_GET['fromdate']) && !empty($_GET['todate'])) {
    $from = $_GET['fromdate'];
    $to = $_GET['todate']; 
    $war = "and date between '$from' and '$to'";
} else { 
    $war = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['fromdate']) && $_GET['fromdate'] != '' && isset($_GET['todate']) && $_GET['todate'] !='' )
  {
    $from = $_GET['fromdate'];
    $to = $_GET['todate']; 
    $war = "and date between '$from' and '$to'";
 }
 else
 { 
    $war = "";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The php function isset($someVar) is used to determine if the value is set. It returns true if the value is emty string/array, is false ... no matter what the value is, if that $someVar has anything, isset() is going to return true.

If you wanna check if the var is defined, and  not empty string/array ... use !empty($someVar).

In php there are alot of situations, where lang consistency is a little misleading.